# If else statement seems to fail executing correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, discord.py

I got a discord Bot in which I want to implement a own logging System. The problem here is that I check if I want to check if the bot was shut down in the last log, it detects it but still does something wrong of which I don't really know what.

This is the relevant code, added some prints for debugging:

```py
for file in get_log_files(path):  # get_log_files yields all log files in the path
    with open(path+file, "r", encoding="cp1252") as f:
         print(not f.read().endswith('Bot wird heruntergefahren'))
         if not f.read().endswith('Bot wird heruntergefahren'):
            return file
         else: print(1)
```

If I execute my bot, which runs at start through the log in `on_ready` this function, it reads the  last log correctly and if shut down before, prints out a False, if not a True. Here now comes the problem:

Doesn't matter which of the two were printed, it never prints the `1` afterwards:
[image: Screenshot of the console]
[image: Another screenshot of the console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you call `f.read()` twice, so the second read will return an empty string because the end of the file was reached after the first read.

What you can do instead is save the output of `f.read().endswith('Bot wird heruntergefahren')` in a variable before printing it and using it in your condition.

Comment: I thought later that it might be because of that, but thanks for explaining ^^